# Mocha test for async Meteor.call

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I am new to both Meteor and Mocha.  It looks like I am not writing the test properly, I would like some help here.

Basically this is what I am trying to do:

1. get status of an app
2. toggle status
3. get current status again
4. check if it's toggled

.

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
  describe('should be able to toggle the status', function() {        

    // check if toggle working
    it('should be able to toggle the status', function(done) {

      // if app is in DB
      if (Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl })) {

        // get the current status
        let status = Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl }).status;

        // run toggle method
        Meteor.call('toggle', Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl }), function(error) {

          if (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
          } else {

            // get the current status again
            const newStatus = Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl }).status;

            // compare
            expect(status).to.equal(!newStatus);
            done();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
 }
```

The questions are:

1. Test finishes before `Meteor.call('toggle')` is done, How do I make it wait til Meteor.call is finished then proceed the test?
2. `if (Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl }))` sometimes is false, I think this `if` statement is called when the app is not yet added to DB, How do I make sure app is added? I am adding the app as:

   ```
   // add app to DB before test
   before(function(done) {
     Meteor.call('addApp', app);
     done();
   });
   ```
3. Is there a way to `// handle error` properly other than `console.log(error)`? I would like Mocha to throw an error and say what was wrong and stop proceeding.

Comment: Can you close the string sequence in the "it" because otherwise the code does not correctly format / highlight

Comment: @Jankapunkt, done

Comment: One partial answer to your third question is calling `done(error)`

Comment: regarding your second question: try to call addAp before your whole test and run the tests on the callback, instead of your "before" method.

Comment: @Jankapunkt, what do you mean by `run the tests on the callback`? sorry about noob question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, comment if it is not working. We can make this work.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    // For Question 2: first call to your addApp
    // addApp should return true, once the app is running
    const isRunning = Meteor.call('addApp', app); 
    assert.isTrue(isRunning);

    describe('should be able to toggle the status', function() {        

        // check if toggle working
        it('should be able to toggle the status', function(done) {

            // ensure that app is defined
            // so no if required
            const currentApp = Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl });
            expect(currentApp ).to.notEqual(null);
            expect(currentApp ).to.notEqual(undefined);

            // get the current status from app
            let status = currentApp.status;

            // run toggle method
            Meteor.call('toggle', Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl }), function(error) {

                if (error) {
                    // Regarding question 3:
                    done(error);
                } else {

                    // get the current status again
                    const newStatus = Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl }).status;

                    // compare
                    expect(status).to.equal(!newStatus);
                    done();
                }
            }); // close call
        }); // close it
  }); // close describe
}
```

Regarding Question 1 I can just say, that using done in callbacks usually works quite fine to make mocha wait until your Meteor.call has been completed. Maybe it resolves your overall problem, if you add the done(error) callback as described regarding question 3.

**Regarding you meteor methods**

Usually you would mock the addApp method's result e.g. with sinon or manually to ensure, that issues in this function do not interfere your tests of toggleApp. I really suggest you to read more into mocking and spying to have more clean and more seperate **units** of tests.

Comment: Dear @Jankapunkt, I tried your code.  However, `const app = Apps.findOne({ url: sampleUrl })` is undefined. It maybe called too soon.  How else can I try?

Comment: Did you put it in the callback of addApp, as shown in the code of my answer? If so, it can't be "too soon" because the code of addApp is at this point already done and app must be initialized. In this case I suggest you to also add the code of the addApp function to your question. There may be another issue that leads to your problem.

Comment: I added `if (err) console.log(err);` after `it`.  Then it showed `Error: Method 'addApp' not found [404]`

Comment: "I may have done something wrong with import" - does that mean, that now everything is running?

Comment: now the method not found error is gone by `import './methods.js'`.  However `const app` is still undefined

Comment: Which is why you should please add your code of the addApp method.

Comment: Ok I see, so first thing is, your addApp method should return true at the very end (when your app successfully runs) and otherwise throw an error on all those points, where it fails. I will adapt the code in my answer.

Comment: did you get it run? If not we may open a chat and solve this out ;)

Comment: I was able to run it, appreciate you very much :)